# Tabbing into menuitem in toolbar shows access indicators

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a toolbar in a usercontrol that contains a menu. When I tab into the menu all access keys in the window are underlined. Is there any way to suppress this behaviour as it looks weird.

You can see this using the following quick sample:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="scratch.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="_First"/>
        <TextBox Text="First" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="_Second"/>
        <TextBox Text="Second" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="_Third"/>
        <TextBox Text="Third" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ToolBar>
        <Button Content="Tool1"/>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem1" />
                <MenuItem Header="SubItem2" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </ToolBar>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Tabbing from the textboxes through the toolbar, you'll see that once the menu gets focus, the access indicators are shown in the labels.